# Click checkbox to copy input value to another input field

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to implement this feature in my app and I would appreciate any tip. So if the user clicks on the Use As Display Name checkbox, I want the value of the App name to be the same as the Display name, like a copy and paste function.

[image]

```js
import { Box, Checkbox, FormControl, FormLabel, Flex, Input } from "@chakra-ui/react"
import { useState } from "react"

export const CreateAnApp = (props) => {

 const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
  name: "",
  displayName: "",
  ,
 });
 const { name, displayName } = formData;

 const onChange = (e) => {
  setFormData((prevState) => ({
    ...prevState,
    [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
  }));
 };

 return ( 
 <Flex mt = {6}>
  <Box>
   <FormControl>
    <FormLabel fontSize = "sm" fontWeight = "semibold">
     App Name 
    </FormLabel>
    <Input fontSize = "14" width = {{ sm: "165px", md: "225px"}} 
      name="name" 
      type = "text" 
      value = {name} 
      onChange = {onChange}
     />
   </FormControl>
    <Checkbox size = 'sm'>Use as display name</Checkbox>
  /Box>
  
 <Box ml = {2}>
  <FormControl>
   <FormLabel fontSize = "sm" fontWeight = "semibold">
    Display Name
   </FormLabel>
   <Input fontSize = "14" width = {{sm: "165px", md: "225px"}} 
     name="displayName"
     type = "text"
     value = {displayName}
     onChange = {onChange}
   />
  </FormControl>
 </Box>
 </Flex>
 )
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `onChange` handler on the `Checkbox`:

```
<Checkbox size = 'sm' onChange={onCheckBoxChange}>Use as display name</Checkbox>
```

Then, `onChange`, copy the `name` from `prevState` to `displayName` if the checkbox is checked:

```
const onCheckBoxChange = (event) => {
    if (event.target.checked) {
        setFormData((prevState) => ({
            ...prevState,
            displayName: prevState.name,
        }));
    }
}
```